# CSS - giving a flex item a margin only when its parent's flex line is wrapped

Tags: css, margin, flexbox

The more I think about this the less feasible it seems, but I was wondering if there was a way to control a flex item's margin based on how it has been laid out in the flex flow.

A screenshot probably explains it best:

[image: stacked]

The 'captured pieces' divs are in a flex container, which is a sibling to the div with the move history in it.  The captured pieces container, and the history, are themselves flex items in another container.  Each captured pieces div has a 3px top margin, to space them out from each other and from the history.

The problem is when there is enough space to display the history div and the 'captured pieces' container side by side, as shown here by artificially shrinking the history div:

[image: side by side]

When they're side by side like this, the 3px top margin is unnecessary - I'd like the top of the 'opponent's captured pieces' to line up with the top of the history.

Is there any way to achieve this with CSS?

Here's the CSS for the relevant divs:

```
div.history_and_captured {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.game_history {
    flex-basis: 15em;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

div.captured_pieces_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="history_and_captured">
    <div class="game_history" id="history">
        <!--history widget is created dynamically-->
    </div>
    <div class="captured_pieces_container">
        <div class="captured_pieces" id="captured_pieces_opponent">
            opponent's captured pieces
        </div>
        <div class="captured_pieces" id="captured_pieces_player">
            player's captured pieces
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the CSS for the parent and child divs.

Comment: Have added the CSS.  I'll add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Using bottom margin rather than top?

Comment: div.game_history<=== No display:flex?

Comment: @HashemQolami - yes that would work for the space between the captured piece divs, but if I added a bottom margin to the history it would still be out of line in the side-by-side situation (unwanted gap at the bottom).

Comment: @Billy_Bob no - display:flex only affects children doesn't it?

Comment: That was a pure speculation. However please consider providing an online example to demonstrate the issue in action. I couldn't reproduce the problem by the posted code.

Comment: @HashemQolami here's an active game - http://jsonchess.com/game/i1exose4.  If you have the window at about 1280x1024 you can see it change from side-by-side to stacking by increasing the board size (buttons in top right)

(if the game isn't there anymore go to 'Current games' and click the board)

Comment: @Gus Hogg-Blake You have 1 child using display:flex. Yes?

Comment: @Billy_Bob yes the captured pieces child is a flex child and a flex container.  the history is only a flex child.

Comment: @GusHogg-Blake I could fix it, sort of. I just gave bottom margin of `.3em` to both the `history` and the `captured_pieces_container` and also added a `min-height` of `3em` to the container itself: `div.captured_pieces_container, div.history { margin-bottom: .3em; } div.captured_pieces_container { min-height: 3em; }`

Comment: @HashemQolami excellent, this is definitely a workable solution and I can't see there being a better way.  thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm loving it. I'm playing for 10 minutes :D

Comment: cool :) have you beat it yet?  it's tuned down but I get smashed every time

Comment: I lose every time :) I hadn't played chess for years. My chess skill sucks :P How does it work? How did you create this? interesting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63291/discussion-between-gus-hogg-blake-and-hashem-qolami).